# How to Calculate Cumulative time difference in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display cumulative time difference in `sql`. Here is the timestamp column. The time difference should be in cumulative form without using temp table but for `id` we can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
Timestamp
2015-05-20 11:23:34.853
2015-05-20 11:21:40.790
2015-05-20 11:20:12.447
2015-05-20 11:19:31.723
2015-05-20 11:19:10.993
```

The result should be like this:

```
TimeDifference
00:00:00
00:01:54
00:01:28
00:00:41
00:00:21
```

Comment: which version are your using? if you are using sql server 2012 or above you can use `LEAD`

Comment: Difference between what? Your output doesn't match your input.

Comment: Hi  Giorgi Nakeuri, its cumulative difference  first row - second row, for the first row it will be 0. from second onwards first row - second row. `declare @dt1 datetime='2015-05-20 11:21:40.790', @dt2 datetime='2015-05-20 11:23:34.853'
select CAST((@dt2-@dt1) as time(0)) as TimeDifference`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF` with `CONVERT` to `Time` and a self join based on order of timestamp to achieve this. Something like this (for SQL Server 2008).

```
;WITH cte as 
(
select '2015-05-20 11:23:34.853' ts
union all select '2015-05-20 11:21:40.790'
union all select '2015-05-20 11:20:12.447'
union all select '2015-05-20 11:19:31.723'
union all select '2015-05-20 11:19:10.993'
), cte2 as 
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts DESC) rn
FROM cte
)
select t1.ts,t2.ts,CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(s,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(s,t1.ts,t2.ts),0),0)) diff
from cte2 t1 LEFT JOIN cte2 t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
```

**Output**

```
ts  ts  diff
2015-05-20 11:23:34.853 NULL    00:00:00.0000000
2015-05-20 11:21:40.790 2015-05-20 11:23:34.853 00:01:54.0000000
2015-05-20 11:20:12.447 2015-05-20 11:21:40.790 00:01:28.0000000
2015-05-20 11:19:31.723 2015-05-20 11:20:12.447 00:00:41.0000000
2015-05-20 11:19:10.993 2015-05-20 11:19:31.723 00:00:21.0000000
```

If you were using SQL 2012, you could have used `LAG` / `LEAD` like this

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(s,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(s,ts,LAG(ts)over(order by ts DESC)),0),0))
FROM cte
ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can number your rows and then with `left join` calc the difference:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( d DATETIME )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '2015-05-20 11:23:34.853' ),
        ( '2015-05-20 11:21:40.790' ),
        ( '2015-05-20 11:20:12.447' ),
        ( '2015-05-20 11:19:31.723' ),
        ( '2015-05-20 11:19:10.993' );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   d ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY d DESC ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  CAST(ISNULL(c2.d - c1.d, 0) AS TIME(0)) TimeDifference
    FROM    cte c1
            LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c2.rn + 1 = c1.rn
```

Output:

```
TimeDifference
00:00:00
00:01:54
00:01:28
00:00:41
00:00:21
```

But be aware that time type can hold up to 24 hours.